# SqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand() works with AddWithValue() but not with Add() - Why?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

[Microsoft's own documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand.aspx#Y0) provides an example of deleting a record as follows:

```
// Create the DeleteCommand.
command = new SqlCommand(
    "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);

// Add the parameters for the DeleteCommand.
parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
    "@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

adapter.DeleteCommand = command;
```

But on my system it doesn't work (complaining about missing @CustomerID). Instead, if I replace the

```
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
```

above with

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 5);
```

[It works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413979/1731850).

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this line:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
```

In this overload, 5 refers to the length of the parameter, not the value. If you want to add the value, you'll have to add the following:

```
command.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value = "5";
```